# ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg'

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, electron, babeljs, fluent-ffmpeg

When I do `yarn add fluent-ffmpeg` i get this issue:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/electron-debug/index.js 96:45-58
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ dll renderer

WARNING in ./node_modules/electron-debug/index.js 97:61-74
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ dll renderer

WARNING in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/options/misc.js 27:21-40
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/fluent-ffmpeg.js
 @ ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js
 @ dll renderer

ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg' in '/Users/yasgur99/Documents/desktopapp/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg'
 @ ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js 1:48-82
 @ dll renderer
```

They said they fixed it in this GitIssue: [here](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/573)

Anyone have any advice?

Some notes: Im using babel, I'm building an electron application

Comment: Try another ffmpeg module

Comment: Fix is here https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/573#issuecomment-305408048

Comment: @namila007, im sorry I had a typo. Not using webpack, using babel. not a solution

Comment: export `'process.env.FLUENTFFMPEG_COV': false` and try

Answer (score 2):

this work for me

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.FLUENTFFMPEG_COV': false
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

***If you have this happening on angular universal app, here is how to fix:***

This error "Can't resolve './lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg'" happens because at the fluent-ffmpeg source code they have this line:

```
module.exports = require(`./lib${process.env.FLUENTFFMPEG_COV ? '-cov' : ''}/fluent-ffmpeg`);
```

So, on build phase this line check if FLUENTFFMPEG_COV is true or false, if true, it will try to require `lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg`, if false will try to require `lib/fluent-ffmpeg`

Now how to fix this? you need a way to inform your angular builder that you want to set this env var FLUENTFFMPEG_COV to false at build phase.

So this leads to another question? How do I set a custom env var to angular build system?

Well, angular builder is under the hood just webpack builder.

We dont have a way to pass build env vars in the angular.json configuration file.

So to set the env var, or further customize the angular builder we need to extend the webpack configuration.

Angular allows us to do this by specifying the builder we want to use.

Follow these steps:

1- create webpack.config.js at the root of the project directory

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.FLUENTFFMPEG_COV': JSON.stringify(false),
    }),
  ],
};
```

2- change the angular builder for the server at the angular.json configuration file

[image]

3- and finally you have to install webpack and @angular-builders/custom-webpack

```
npm install --save-dev webpack @angular-builders/custom-webpack
```